# Why did come this error when I call API ?'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I would like to show the data in the template from the backend by calling the API I made. But the below error shows up. Why it came? Give me a relevant solution...
***views.py:***

```
class CourseViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

def CourseInfo(request):
    callApi = request.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/courses/').json()
    context = {
        "queryset":callApi
    }
    return render(request, 'insert.html',context)
```

***urls.py:***

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('courses', views.CourseViewSet, basename='course')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CourseInfo, name='CourseInfo'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

***models.py:***

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
```

***Error:***

```
AttributeError at /
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?coursename=Bangla&courseauthor=Mossaddak&courseprice=23322&coursediscount=234&courseduration=23
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\7_ProgrammingLanguage\1_FrameWork\4_Django-Rest-Frame-work\2_CBVproject\CBVapp\views.py, line 32, in CourseInfo
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DCL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\7_ProgrammingLanguage\\1_FrameWork\\4_Django-Rest-Frame-work\\2_CBVproject',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\DCL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Oct 2022 23:10:07 +0000
```

Comment: It is `requests.get`, not `request.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django request module does not have any .get method for API response you should use the python requests module like this

step -1

```
pip install requests
```

step - 2

```
import requests
def SigninView(request):
    p=requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    print(p.json())
    return render(request,'index.html',)
```

for more info visit this link

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-json-python-requests/

Comment: Thank you, though @willem already has given the solution and I solved

Comment: Grate all the best